# Merging Tiles PHP (Wordpress Theme: Planar - lite)

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Sorry if this is a novice question, I would really appreciate any help. I'm customizing a wordpress theme and reached a point where I feel I have to merge PHP functions to get the results I'm looking for.

The theme is responsive and breaks posts into tiles. However, the tiles are broken up as Image and then post content. I was thinking I need to merge the tiles so the thumbnail image is the background of the post tile. Is this possible?

**Image tile function**

```
<figure class="tile" style="background: <?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'planar_additional_color', '#398ece' ) ); ?><?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'planar-quadratum' );  if( !empty($thumbnail) ) { ?> url(<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>) no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position:50%<?php } ?>;">

        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blank.png" alt="" width="800" height="800" /> 

    </figure>
```

**Post function**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('tile post'); ?>>

        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blank.png" alt="" width="800" height="800" />

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="tile-content<?php if ( !has_post_thumbnail())  : ?> no-thumbnail<?php endif; ?>" rel="bookmark">

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php
            $category = get_the_category(); 
            echo '<h3>' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</h3>';

            if ( has_post_format() ) :
                echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
            endif; 
        ?>

    <span><time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>"><?php the_date('j F Y', '<br />', '<br />'); ?></time></span>

    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

</a><!-- .tile-content -->

</article>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help, knowing where to put the new background attribute was super helpful. Here's the functioning code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('tile post'); ?> style="background: <?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'planar_additional_color', '#398ece' ) ); ?><?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'planar-quadratum' );  if( !empty($thumbnail) ) { ?> url(<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>) no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position:50%<?php } ?>;">
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail ?>"` to whichever element you want the background image on.

Assuming the article tag:

```
//to get the URL 
<?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'planar-quadratum' ); ?>

//display
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('tile post'); ?> style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail)">
  //code...
</article
```

Comment: Sure thing, would you mind terribly marking the answer as accepted if it did indeed fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks for posting the code snippet. It placed a blank image, which is good but it's not the featured image for that post. Should I be using "get_template_directory_uri" or something else to get the featured image to display?

Comment: Ah, I thought that was a placeholder URL for the purposes of this question. Give me a moment and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: you are missing a closing php tag

Comment: Thank you for the help. The theme called for a lot of other attributes, so to keep the theme functioning I needed to take: `style="background: <?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'planar_additional_color', '#398ece' ) ); ?><?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'planar-quadratum' );  if( !empty($thumbnail) ) { ?> url(<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>) no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position:50%<?php } ?>;">` and paste it where you directed me to place the background image. The difference was using the "background:" tag instead of "background-image:"

Comment: @David Ah, yes. You are correct good sir. @ user5954331 That is one way to do it, I was trying to avoid making it all inline for you, but if it work, then by all means.